# Jquery - Hide Div if other than button else where clicked on DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a Div container with contents and button. What I want to happen is this:

- If the user clicks on `<div>` or its contents, hide the `<div>` and its contents.
- If the user clicks on `<button>` inside of the `<div>`, then don't hide the `<div>` or its contents.

What I mean is that it always happens, **unless** the user clicks the `button` inside of the `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container active">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>teressdsasas</p>
    <div class="ticket-nos">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="btn-left">
                <div class="input-group--btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default ticket-nos-btn minus" type="button" data-type="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.container').on('touchstart', function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check where this is a button or not...

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);    
    if (target.parent('div.container').length || target.is('div.container'))
    {
        if(target.is('div.container'))
        {           
            $('div.container').hide();

        }
        else
        {  
             // Do something here....
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(target);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your code.. still when i click button, it hides.. its not ignoring button.

Comment: Updated my HTML structure. Like this only i have in my code.. cant able to trigger button, has "container" is parent container. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the event `stopPropagation()` to button selector

```
$(".ticket-nos-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check on tag name of the [target of the event](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/). It it is button the do whatever you want to do.

Note: dont forget to [stop the propogation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false;` by clicking the `button`:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'p', function() {
  $(this).hide();
})

$(document).on('click', 'p button', function() {
  console.log('button click');
  return false;
})
```

```css
p {
  padding: 40px;
  border: dashed 2px lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button>button</button>
```